# Open CTI-Softphone Layout

Tags: cti

I was going through some docs and it says to configure "SoftPhone Layouts" and assign them to users but In Open CTI Developer's Guide, I am not seeing any reference to configuring layout. Does SoftPhone Layouts only applies to CTI 4.0 and before not to Open CTI?

Would appreciate your insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Softphone Layouts are needed for OpenCTI based integration also, if you are planning on using Screenpop Functions of the OpenCTI API.  The Softphone layout should be assigned to User Profiles, for whom the screenpops has to happen.

SearchandScreenpop, Screenpoponly and Searchonly  OpenCTI functions need softphone layout configured.